# How to set class name to <a> tag in CodeIgniter pagination

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I need to set class name to `<a>` tag in CodeIgniter pagination.
CodeIgniter's `$this->pagination->create_links();` function creates links like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/pages/3">3</a>
```

But, I need link like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/pages/3" class="number">3</a>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'class="number" ';
```

before

```
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

Comment: You're right. When using `$this->pagination->initialize()`, the `class="` is not added automatically. When using the global config file however, it is ... inconsistent behaviour is tricky sometimes ;-)

Comment: I agree..Also I like to say. Syntax of pagination is depend on the version of  codeigniter. You can go through my below answer..

Answer (score 14):

This is the below code using this you can add the class inside the anchor tag of pagination in Code Ignitor

```
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'myclass');
```

Comment: Syntax of pagination is depend on the version of codeigniter. You can go through my below answer..

Comment: this is the right way to do it. this deserves tick. the ticked solutions does not work actually.

Answer (score 7):

**2.** This **attributes** will work in above version of CI 3.1

```
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'myclass');
```

NOTE: For More Refer: system/libraries/Pagination.php.
You will find below lines..

> // Deprecated legacy support for the anchor_class option

> // Should be removed in CI 3.1+

**1.** This configuration is **deprecated** below (CI 3.1) version.

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'number';
```

Answer (score 4):

From CodeIgniter's [manual on the Pagination class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/pagination.html):

> **Adding a class to every anchor**
>
> If you want to add a class attribute to every link rendered by the
>   pagination class, you can set the config "anchor_class" equal to the
>   classname you want.

So you simply write

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'class="number"';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
```

before you use the pagination.

---

If you want to change this globally:

> If you prefer not to set preferences using the above method, you can
>   instead put them into a config file. Simply create a new file called
>   pagination.php, add the $config array in that file. Then save the file
>   in: config/pagination.php and it will be used automatically. You will
>   NOT need to use the $this->pagination->initialize function if you save
>   your preferences in a config file.

---

Edit: CodeIgniters Pagination library behaves a bit inconsistent.

When using the `$this->pagination->initialize($config);` manually, you need to specify the attribute on your own:

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'class="number"';
```

However, when using the config-file, it is added automatically, so you have to use

```
$config['anchor_class'] = 'number';
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this one line of code for add class on the anchor tag

```
$config['attributes'] = array('class' => 'page-link');
```